# Flutter app - Google sign in doesn't work after publishing to PlayStore

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-signin, publish, sha1

I use Firebase authentication with google_sign_in for my CrossPlatform Mobile app that's been developed with Flutter framework.

The problem :

- When I press the login button on the published app to log in I get the following exception :

```
Platformexception(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

Notes :

- No problems are visible when I run 'flutter doctor -v'
- It works completely well on Ios and on debug / release mode when I run it from my computer on my phone, but the published version is not working. (flutter run, flutter run --release)
- I use app signing provided by google

What I've tried so far :

- I've already added the app-signing SHA1 and SHA256 keys from Play Store's console and the upload and release keys from my upload-keystore.jks to Firebase APP
- I've tried to recreate my Firebase Android app, readding google-service.json
- I've added this part to my build.gradle to test if the default shrinking is the problem :

```
buildTypes {
release {
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
}
}
```

I know this error is most likely relatd to SHA keys, so if somebody could explain which SHA1 & SHA256 Keys should be added and exactly how should I generate them, that would be nice also, just to exclude that possibility completely. Also I'd be grateful for any other insights.

Answer (score 3):

Google uses ***Automatic App Signing*** by default, which means that your SHA-key will change after you upload to Google Play.

To find the new key, go to the **Play console > Setup > App Integrity > App Signing** (or click on this link: https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/keymanagement).

You will find three keys there: MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256.

Now you just have to add those keys in the Firebase console under **Project settings > General**.

Answer (score 0):

With iOS, you don't need to care about adding sha key

With Android, I think mostly you've missed adding sha **app signing key**

When you run your project (both debug & release mode), this behavior is the same you install an APK to the device, and local keystore (also called **upload keystore** - the key you generated by yourself) is fine in this case

But when you install your app from Google Play (or internal testing or whatever through Google Play), google uses **app signing key** to sign your app (not your upload keystore) like image below, so miss adding this sha key will cause the error
[image]

-> Solution: find your app signing key on the dashboard like the image below and add it to your config

[image]